# Authentication session expires on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to log a user into an ASP.NET MVC site, and the session expires very quickly, in minutes.
Authentication is done in one line of code:

```
authProvider.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

Then I have in Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="300" slidingExpiration="true">
```

and the setting on the IIS on the server for 300 minutes.

What is the problem?

Comment: Isn't it because your `sessionState timeout` has a low value?

Comment: those are minutes. so it should expire in 300 minutes, but it expires in 5.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `forms timeout` but the `sessionState timeout`

Comment: I added the timeout property to the session state, but still the same behavior:
`    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout ="300">
    <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
    </sessionState>`

Comment: What value do you have in the `Idle Time-out` parameter or your Application Pool? Please refer to this [article](http://aspnetfaq.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39866953/1351076).

Comment: @krlzlx you are correct! the value was 5 and now changing it to 300 saves the session. This is an amazing answer that I feel must be rewarded, if you would like to answer the question. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a `sessionState timeout` value that matches your `forms timeout`:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
         name=".ASPXAUTH"
         timeout="300"
         slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="300" mode="InProc" />
</system.web>
```

You also need to change the `Idle Time-out` parameter of your Application Pool to the desired authentification timeout to avoid the Application Pool to recycle too soon and therefore lose your sessions.

This parameter can be found in:

> IIS - Application Pools - Advanced Settings of the Application Pool in question.

References:

- [Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [IIS7 Application Pool Idle Time-out Settings](http://aspnetfaq.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/)

If you don't want to change this parameter(*), a solution is to use the `StateServer` mode of the Session State. This mode uses a service to store the session instead of the memory with `In-Process` mode. It has the advantage of not losing the session when the Application Pool is recycled. It's also very easy to configure:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=loopback:42424"
       cookieless="false"
       timeout="300" />
</system.web>
```

(*) 5 minutes is very low. The default is 20 minutes. So I advice to set it to at least the default value if using the `StateServer` mode.

Reference:

- [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)

Comment: Hello, so this worked for two months. now it doesn't any more. I see there are two cookies set , one  Cookies/.ASPXAUTH (expires "When the browsing session ends") and another in Local Storage / name of my website (subdomain.domain.com, but does not have any associated metadata with it? ) . what do you advise?

Comment: I advise you to try the `StateServer` mode of the Session State like described in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. I have now added both and I still lose the session in around 15 minutes. Should the text inside stateConnectionString be different than "tcpip=loopback:42424"?

Comment: No, that setting should work. Did you set the `timeout` to 300? You can check this setting in IIS -> YourSite -> Session State -> Cookie Settings - `Time-out (in minutes)` should be 300.

Comment: Yes it is 
my webconfig is: 
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="300" slidingExpiration="true">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="1" password="1" />
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=loopback:42424"
       cookieless="false"
       timeout="300" />
    <pages>
    I publish with:
    - delete all existing files
    - precompile during publish
    - exclude files from App_Data folder